# Magento Admin Panel shows only header with menu?

Tags: admin-panel

When I login to the admin panel, only  header is displaying with menu. All the menu items are visible and every page shows only header section( footer is not showing too).

I checked the log files too..and there is nothing.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check view page source, there should be fatal error in footer as fatal error stop the further execution and that's why footer section is not displaying.

Comment: I checked the page source and is no error..

Comment: check div section like header, container, footer are loaded properly or not

Comment: header is completely loaded and and in body section  <div class="header"> is completely loaded. After that nothing is loaded.

Comment: send  screenshot of a page.

Comment: The problem is fixed...created a new instance in server and moved all files to there.